# Understanding Querysets, creating the perfect database relationship

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm am currently trying to figure out the best way to structure my database schema based on a few models. I'll try and explain this the best I can so I can work out the best way to tackle the problem.

Firstly, I have 3 models that are "related"

`User` which is extended to contain the field `api_key`, `Campaign` and finally `Beacon`.

`User`'s can have many `Campaign`'s but a `Campaign` can only relate to one `User` my first choice here was to have `Campaign` have a foreign key to `User`, correct me if I'm wrong, but I feel that is the best choice there. Likewise, `Campaign` can have many `Beacon`'s but a `Beacon` can only relate to one `Campaign` at a time. Again, I'm presuming that a foreign key here would work the best.

The issue arises when I try and query the `Beacon`'s that relate to any given `Campaign`. I wish to return all `Beacon`'s that relate to the `User` whilst also getting the data for `Campaign`.

I wish to return a JSON string like the following:

```
{
    XXXX-YYYYY: {
        message: "Hello World",
        destination: "http://example.com"
    }
    XXXX-YYYYY: {  
        message: "Hello World",
        destination: "http://example.com"
    }
}
```

XXXX-YYYYY being the `Beacon.factory_id` and message/destination being `Campaign.message` and `Campaign.destination`

I'm thinking Queryset's here, but I've never worked with them before and it just confused me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question, you have something like this:

```
 class User(models.Model):
      pass

 class Campaign(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Attached to")
      message = models.CharField()
      destination = models.CharField()

 class Beacon(models.Model):
      factory_id = models.CharField()
      campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, verbose_name="Campaign")
```

You can [follow `ForeignKey` "backward"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward), by using `campaign_set` generated attribute:

> If a model has a `ForeignKey`, instances of the foreign-key model will have access to a Manager **that returns all instances of the first model**. By default, this Manager **is named `FOO_set`,** where `FOO` is the source model name, lowercased.

So you can query your `Beacon` model like this:

```
beacon = Beacon.objects.get(factory_id="XXXX-YYYYY")
# Get every campaigns related and only relevant fields (in a list of dict)
campaigns = beacon.campaign_set.all().values('message', 'destination')

for campaign in campaigns:
    print(campaign['message'])
    print(campaign['destination'])
```

For your dictionary, it is impossible to make it exactly like this. You can't have a duplicate key.

Comment: fantastic, this answers it perfectly.  In relation to your last comment "For your dictionary, it is impossible to make it exactly like this. You can't have a duplicate key." the XXXX-YYYYY was just a placeholder, it will be a unique key dictated by factory_id, of which no two would be alike.

Comment: @NeilAshleyHickman Ok, I thought you had multiple Beacon object with the same `factory_id`, my bad :-)

Comment: I didn't clarify, you weren't to know :) thanks for giving it such details it's really helped me understand the principle now.

Answer (score 0):

*I wish to return all `Beacons` that relate to the `User` whilst also getting the data for `Campaign`*

```
beacons = Beacon.objects.filter(campaign__user=user).select_related('campaign')
```

You can then easily process this into your desired data structure.

*I'm thinking Querysets here, but I've never worked with them before and it just confused me*

A `QuerySet` is simply how the Django ORM represents a query to your database that results in a set of items. So the above is a QuerySet, as is something as simple as `User.objects.all()`. You can read some introductory material about QuerySets in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects).